# Get specific file with glob

Tags: python, xml, glob

I am trying to locate a specific .xml file with glob. But the path comes from an object, and it doesn't seem to work.

I followed this example: [Python: How can I find all files with a particular extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608411/python-how-can-i-find-all-files-with-a-particular-extension)

The code is this:

```
import glob
ren_folder = 'D:\Sentinel\D\S2A_OPER_PRD_MSIL1C_PDMC_20160710T162701'
glob.glob(ren_folder+'/'s*.xml)
```

I get invalid syntax...

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you just mixing up your forward- and back-slashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glob.glob(ren_folder+'/'s*.xml)
```

You are closing the flie name string prematurely, it should be:

```
glob.glob(ren_folder+'/s*.xml')
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
glob.glob(os.path.join(ren_folder, 's*.xml'))
```